# Automatic backup from SSH-server

Tags: mysql, batch

I am in needed of a script (. Bat) who log on to an SSH server, and perform a backup of my mysql database with the help of mysqldump.

This is to be run on a Windows computer and run three times per day.

I do not really know where I should start, but it ought to be finished examples on the net that I can use?

The requirements
Log in to an ssh server
Make a backup
save the backup on my local machine
This should be done three times per day

What software is needed? do you have any solutions I can work on?

The ultimate would have been one. Bat file somewhere on your computer that runs three times a day and do this without opening up a lot of programs.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what platform is the mysql database running on?

Comment: Im not sure, but i think my webhost use Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at PuTTY: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Using a private SSH key (PuTTYgen), you should be able to connect to your server via SSH (PuTTYtel), run the backup and then pull the backup to your local PC (PSCP). Should be quite "automatable".

Comment: This tutorial might help

Comment: Did you forget to attach a link? ;-)

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty